# How do I optimize this python code using cython?

Tags: python, optimization, cython

I have some python code, and I'm wondering what I can do to optimize the speed for creating the array using Cython.  Note that I have tried other methods: [Counting Algorithm Performance Optimization in Pypy vs Python (Numpy vs List)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818691/counting-algorithm-performance-optimization-in-pypy-vs-python-numpy-vs-list)

It seems like Cython is significantly faster than anything I've tried before right out of the box.  I am wondering if I can get even more performance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def create_array(size=4):
    """
    Creates a multi-dimensional array from size
    """
    array = [(x, y, z)
             for x in xrange(size)
             for y in xrange(size)
             for z in xrange(size)]
    return array
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will be a slow operation regardless of how you do it. Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use a NumPy array?

Comment: I've tried the NumPy route; it is far too slow.  I should have something close to c parity (about 2ms for 32x32x32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't help with the `cython`-code, but I believe this operation can still be done efficiently in `numpy`, you just haven't looked deep enough yet.

```
def variations_with_repetition(alphabetlen):
    """Return a list of all possible sets of len=3 with elements
    chosen from range(alphabetlen)."""

    a = np.arange(alphabetlen)
    z = np.vstack((
        np.repeat(a,alphabetlen**2),
        np.tile(np.repeat(a,alphabetlen),alphabetlen),
        np.tile(a,alphabetlen**2))).T
    return z
```

Now, execution speed here is meaningless in this case because you just mention you want it below 2ms for `alphabetlen=32`. That depends on your CPU. But I can *compare* your own proposed method to this one:

```
In [4]: %timeit array = [(x, y, z) for x in xrange(size) for y in xrange(size) for z in xrange(size)]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.3 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit variations_with_repetition(32)
1000 loops, best of 3: 348 µs per loop
```

That's well below your desires 2ms speed. But once again, your mileage may vary depending on the CPU.

Comment: Thank you for this.  It's not exactly what I wanted, but I will accept it.  In addition, I had really wanted to go the numpy route since I need to do transformations on the data later.